np.repeat inplace solution to avoid memory reallocation
How can I assign np.repeat (or equivalent function) output to existing memory? (many numpy functions have an "out=" parameter to do this). This reassignment would be very useful because I have a (extremely big) previously created array of the same size (as the new one) that I am not using anymore through the rest of my program. Reusing its place in memory would allow me to avoid a lot of memory reallocation.
I have tried this, but it does not accelerate the allocation.
diff_da1[:,:,:] = np.repeat(np.linalg.norm(diffs, axis=2)[:, :, None], repeats=d, axis=2)
dist_point_vertex = diff_da1

This broadcasting trick accelerates slightly:
diff_da1[:,:,:] = np.linalg.norm(diffs, axis=2)[:,:,None]
dist_point_vertex = diff_da1

Still far from fast.
Hint: A similar but more general question would be: How to place the result of an operation involving n numpy arrays in a previously allocated memory space different to the corresponding to those n arrays?

Update: Minimal reproducible code example
vector_set_1 = np.random.rand(1500,2)
vector_set_2 = np.random.rand(1500,2)

# allocate target memory space
first_allocation = np.einsum('ij,kj->ik', vector_set_1, vector_set_2)

# do something useful with the first allocation

# produce new tensor with the same shape 
object_to_be_repeated = np.einsum('ij,ij->i', vector_set_1, vector_set_1)
first_allocation[:,:] = object_to_be_repeated[:,None]

# compute some inplace operations with the new values
first_allocation.__iadd__(first_allocation)


So far, this is the fastest way I've found to do it.
np.copyto(first_allocation, object_to_be_repeated[:, None])


Do you really need those repeats?  Depending on else you are doing that (n,m,1) shaped array would be enough.

This is what I am doing after with that array:
        dist_point_vertex[~ mask] = INFNTY

        np.cos(alphas_orth_ref, out=alphas_orth_ref, where=mask)

        np.cos(phis_orth_ref, out=phis_orth_ref, where=mask)

        np.multiply(dist_point_vertex, alphas_orth_ref, out=dist_point_vertex, where=mask)

        np.divide(dist_point_vertex, phis_orth_ref, out=dist_point_vertex, where=mask)

        return np.min(dist_point_vertex, axis=1, initial=INFNTY, where=mask)


I tried to add the unreadable comment code to your question.  Even with editing it's hard to follow.  All that use of out and where may save time, but it doesn't make for readable code. Anyways, your broadcasted assjgnment is probably the best you can do.  There are some low level functions like copyto and put, but I don't use them enough to know if they are applicable or faster.

Could you create minimal reproducible example? And maybe clean the "comment code" too

profiling may be needed as well.  The followup lines seem to work with similar size arrays.

nice you added example, now focus on word minimal :)

When you do the broadcasted assignment, two things happen:

The scalar gets wrapped in an array view that has the correct dimensions but no stride, which is cheap
The view gets copied into each element of the output buffer, which can be expensive

You could try to bypass part two by manually creating the broadcast wrapper and assigning it directly to your output. You will eventually eat the cost, but not up front:
dist_point_vertex = np.broadcast_to(np.linalg.norm(diffs, axis=2)[:, :, None], dist_point_vertex.shape)

In this case, get rid of the intermediate buffer diff_da1 entirely, and keep in mind that the shape may have to come from somewhere other than dist_point_vertex.shape.
Another option to np.broadcast_to is np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.
If you absolutely need the expanded array, your best bet is to do broadcasting. However, can avoid the call to np.repeat using the keepdims argument to np.linalg.norm:
diff_da1[:, :, :] = np.linalg.norm(diffs, axis=-1, keepdims=True)


You are right. The problem in my case is that, after producing the result, I need to be able to perform inplace operations on it. Therefore I need the most efficient way posible of placing the result of the operation in an already allocated (but with no further use) piece of memory.

@MiguelMontes. I added a paragraph to the end of the answer that might help
